# Why doesn't associated type synonym imply the constraint

Tags: haskell, type-families

Why doesn't using an associated type synonym in a signature imply the corresponding constraint?

E.g. why doesn't the following compile:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications, ScopedTypeVariables, TypeFamilies, AllowAmbiguousTypes #-}

class MyClass a where
  type AssociatedType a 
  bar :: Int

foo :: forall a. AssociatedType a -> Int
foo _ = bar @a
```

ghc 8.6.5 gives the following error:

```
error:
    * No instance for (MyClass a) arising from a use of `bar'
      Possible fix:
        add (MyClass a) to the context of
          the type signature for:
            foo :: forall a. AssociatedType a -> Int
    * In the expression: bar @a
      In an equation for `foo': foo _ = bar @a
  |
8 | foo _ = bar @a
  |         ^^^^^^
```

GHC documentation doesn't seem to mention this aspect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it implied the constraint, then anybody using values of the associated value in any way whatsoever would need to have the constraint in scope. For example,

```
sort :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
```

obviously knows nothing about `MyClass`, yet it should be possible to use it as `sort :: [AssociatedType a] -> [AssociatedType a]` provided that you have `Ord (AssociatedType a)` in the *calling* scope.

To get behaviour like the one you seem to be looking for, you want a *wrapped constraint* rather than an associated type. That can't be done with `-XTypeFamilies`, but it can be done with `-XGADTs`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}

class MyClass a where
  bar :: Int

data MyClassWitness a where
  MyClassWitness :: MyClass a => MyClassWitness a

foo :: ∀ a. MyClassWitness a -> Int
foo MyClassWitness = bar @a
```

Instead of a self-rolled wrapper you can also use the one from the [`constraints` library](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/constraints):

```
import Data.Constraint

foo :: ∀ a . Dict (MyClass a) -> Int
foo Dict = bar @a
```

Important in both cases is that you actually pattern-match on the GADT constructor, as only that actually brings the constraint into scope. This would **not** work:

```
foo :: ∀ a . Dict (MyClass a) -> Int
foo _ = bar @a
```

Answer (score 2):

Because just using the type does not require the type constraint. For instance, this compiles:

```
foo :: forall a. AssociatedType a -> Int
foo _ = 42
```

At runtime, there is no need to pass a typeclass dictionary to this function, which is coherent with the lack of the constraint during type checking.

In your code, the constraint is needed because you are using `bar`, not because you are using the type.